# Run a JavaScript program in Windows 8.1

Tags: javascript, windows, wsh

I downloaded a js program that I was working on in codeacademy.  It's a cash register program.  You can see it [here](http://1drv.ms/1tJVwdn)  I know the code works in a console.

What I was trying to do was run it in windows, like a regular program.

I opened an elevated cmd window and typed `cscript.exe "C:\<location>\register.js"` 
and got 
`Input Error: There is no script engine for file extension ".js".`

I registered the jscript.dll successfully using `regsvr32.exe jscript.dll`. Ran again.  Same error.

I associated .js files with an engine using `assoc .js=JSFILE`. Ran again.  Same error.

I have also tried wscript.exe.  Same error.

Not sure what's going on.  The end goal for me is to run a JavaScript program in a windows environment.  I believe this is the way to go about it but am running into the errors.  I'm probably missing something.

Comment: See [`nodejs`](http://nodejs.org/)

Comment: Did you register jscript.dll using an elevated prompt?

Comment: everything was run at an elevated prompt

Comment: Xotic750.. do you mind explaining a little bit about how using node.js helps me with this.  I'm new to programming.  I installed it, opened it, and it just gives me prompt.  No idea what to do from there.  Is this something I'm going to just have to dig into and read about?  I thought cscript was a good way to simply run my js.

Comment: @spex5, JS isn't a language that is meant to be run in windows CMD. Where did you initially run it? On the website or on a linux machine? NodeJS runs JS scripts locally (ie. not in a browser) and console.log statements will be output to the CMD window. To use Node with this script just run `node C:\<location>\register.js`.

Comment: @LcLk thanks for the explanation.  I ran it from the debugger in chrome as well as codeacademy's teaching environment.  I see that I can run individual commands in node .. like console.log("me").  However, if I run the same console.log saved into a js file, the output seems to hang displaying 3 dots

Comment: I downloaded the file `register.js` and then in the command prompt typed `node register.js` and got the following output `Your bill is 13.74`

Comment: like I said, I'm new to this so it wasn't obvious to be at first.. but I typed `C:\Program Files\nodejs>node.exe "C:\Scripts\register.js"` into a cmd prompt and it worked.

Comment: How come if I run `console.log("me");` from the node.js directly, I get the correct output.. but if I run `node.exe console.log("me");` from the cmd prompt, I get an error `Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\console.log(me);'`

Comment: Because the executable expects a file as it's argument not a javascript command.

Comment: I figured that.  But why can I get an output from the node.js cmd prompt?  `console.log("me");  ----> me` in node.js.. but not if I run the same line from the windows cmd prompt `node.exe console.log("me");`  .. is it not doing the same thing?

Comment: No. From the node console prompt it is expecting a javascript command. From a windows command prompt it is expecting a windows executable. The executable in this case is `node.exe` and by default this executable expects the following argument to be the file name of a text file that contains javascript commands.

Comment: Execute the script with the specified script engine: `cscript.exe //E:JScript "C:\<location>\register.js"`